# He wears blue jeans vs. He has blue jeans on

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

Hello dear English friends,

I just wondered whether the expressions "He wears blue jeans." vs "He has blue jeans on." differ in meaning. To my mind the second sentence sounds kind of wrong.

I mean I can say "I put my jeans on." but would someone say "hey guys, how are you I have my new jeans on, did you notice?"

Thanks

Comment: "He has blue jeans on" means he is wearing the jeans right now. "He wears blue jeans" means right now he could be wearing swimming trunks.

Comment: Somebody would say either *"Hey guys, I have my new jeans on. Did you notice?"* or *"Hey guys, I'm wearing my new jeans. Did you notice?"* We wouldn't say *"Hey guys, I wear my new jeans. Did you notice?"* because for most verbs, the simple present tense means it's a habitual action.

Comment: Thanks :). So in general the expression "to have sth. on" can be used in normal speech? I thought it sounded kind of wrong and the verb "to wear", in this case wearing then, would be more accurate.

Comment: Yes, the expression "to have sth. on" is commonly used in colloquial speech.

Comment: Yes, _to have [something]_ (or _nothing!_) _on_ is perfectly normal (e.g. the 1930s song 'The sun has got his hat on').

Comment: Don't quote that, Kate, there are some dodgy bits...

Comment: @tb11 Would you suggest to not use this expression in written text?

Comment: @Phil the expression can be used in written text too, unless the text is very formal.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have%20on

Comment: He's wearing blue jeans.

Comment: "He wears blue jeans" means that he is in the habit of wearing blue jeans but does not necessarily mean that he has them on at the moment. If people are in a social setting all dressed casually, the wife of one of the men might say "he wears a suit to work". He's not wearing a suit at the time but he will be wearing one when he sets off for work on Monday morning.

Answer (score 2):

> He wears blue jeans

is present simple tense and so it suggests that he repeatedly or habitually wears blue jeans.

Interestingly

> He has blue jeans on

is also present simple, but it seems to imply the present moment and so would be better compared with the present continuous:

> He is wearing blue jeans.

I can't explain why this might be and hopefully someone else will be able to shed some light on that.

Comment: For stative verbs, like *has*, we don't use the present continuous. We would not say *he is having two cars*, but *he has two cars*. We would say *he is having breakfast*, but in that meaning, *to have* is not a stative verb. [See this webpage.](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/stative-verbs)

Comment: Thank you @Peter. Yes it occurred to me later, while I was driving the car, that *has* is stative and as such has no continuous (progressive) tense and because of that a stative verb in the present simple also implies the present moment or as John says below "right now".

Comment: "He has blue jeans on" doesn't *imply* the present moment, it simply says it.

Answer (score 1):

For stative predicates like *own* or *be tall*, the present tense just means present time:

- *Sandra owns the house.* (right now)
- *Frank is tall.*  (right now)

But for active predicates like *run* or *write*, the present tense means **generic** action:

- *Bill runs in this neighborhood.* (i.e, it's his habit)
- *Mary writes.* (i.e, it's her occupation, or hobby)

To refer to the present time with an active verb, one uses the progressive construction:

- *Bill is running in this neighborhood.* (right now)
- *Mary is writing.* (right now)

So, since *wear* is active, and *have* is stative,

- *He wears blue jeans.*

means wearing blue jeans is his normal habit, but it says nothing about what he's wearing right now, while

- *He has blue jeans on.*

means he's wearing them right now.

Comment: *He has money*, though stative, can go either way. *He has money in his pocket* also can go either way, though is much more likely to mean right now. But then we have *He has politicians in his pocket*, which is most likely to be habitual. Go figure.

Comment: _Have_ is a busy verb.

Answer (score 0):

He has blue jeans on= He is wearing blue jeans

He wears blue jeans- simple present tense

He is wearing blue jeans- present continuous/progressive tense

'He has blue jeans on' means 'He is wearing blue jeans right now'.

He wears blue jeans does not denote that 'He is wearing blue jeans right now'.
It refers to a habit.